# lambda function uses member variable and produces different results

Tags: java, function, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

I dont know why the code runs without errors. From what I learned, in functional programming, same input results in same output and function's internal state cannot be changed from outside. When I created the function 'add', it uses the value of variable `value` which is 100. this results in 105 when added with 5. But when I set `value` to 10, how the already created function 'add' changes its internal state and produces 15 when added with 5?

```
public class mine {
  int value;

  public Function<Integer, Integer> createFunction() {
    return (m) -> m + value;
  }

  public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

public class ClosureCheck {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    mine a = new mine();
    a.setValue(100);
    Function<Integer, Integer> add = a.createFunction();
    System.out.println(add.apply(5));
    a.setValue(10);
    System.out.println(add.apply(5));
  }
}
```

results:
`105 15`

In other words, why for the same input, it produces different answer?

I expect the same answer 105 irrespective of the value of `value` after creating the 'add' function.

Comment: For your assumption to be correct, your function needs to be stateless. But it does have a state since it uses the `value` field. Your code explicitly uses that field so I don't understand why this result confuses you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your confusion. You're using the class variable `value` for your calculations and then *change* that value in between calculations.

Comment: " From what i learned, in functional programming..." You're writing java, which doesn't enforce functional programming that's up to you. The part that isn't changing is `this` which refers to a `mine` object that has a mutable field `value`. If you want the result of `add` to not be changeable you can create a local final variable for value. Then it won't change when you change the field.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but it seems to me that OP was expecting that the created function `return (m) -> m + value;` would have taken a 'snapshot' of `value` at the moment of invoking `createFunction` (this is obviously not the case).

Comment: “in functional programming, same input results in same output”—that’s correct but nobody said that only things to the left of a `->` qualify as input. Given the same input, i.e. the same values for `m` and `value`, you will get the same output. Even `() -> Math.random()` will produce the same output for the same input, but you must consider the state of the RNG as input to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct there is a closure on the lambda, but it is with a mutable object.

```
return (m) -> m + value;
```

That is short hand notation for.

```
return (m) -> m + this.value;
```

The `this` is final and does not change for the duration of the `Function`. `this.value` can change because this is a `mine` instance that is mutable. If you want the value itself to be immutable then you need to create a local version, which needs to be effectively final to be used in the lambda.

```
int v = this.value;
return (m) -> m + v;
```

I think this new statement would better illustrate what you expect from a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

> From what I learned, in functional programming, same input results in
> same output and function's internal state cannot be changed from
> outside.

is at least incomplete, that is true only for **pure functional programming**, i.e. a paradigm in which functions are stateless.

Alas, Java functional programming is **impure**. You can have stateful lambdas. This is exactly what you experimented.
You can be pure in Java but it is a matter of discipline.

You may read [pure functions in functional programming](https://adabeat.com/fp/pure-functions-in-functional-programming/#:%7E:text=Impure%20functions%20have%20side%20effects,changing%20the%20state%20of%20objects) for more considerations on the subject.